# Deleting multiple items in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a list of items need to be passed which should be deleted. How can I do this in PHP?

```
$query = "DELETE from members WHERE member_id ='$chan[2]' ";
```

`$chan[2]` holds multiple values, but deletes only one.

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific.  When you say "multiple values", what do you mean?  An array?  comma-separated values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$chan[2] refers to one element in the $chan array.  So, I think you mean that $chan has multiple values.

Try this:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM members WHERE member_id IN (" . implode(", ", $chan) . ");";
```

Comment: Please note that that code doesn't protect from SQL injection!  Make sure to sanitize any data in $chan before using that code!

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$query = "DELETE FROM members WHERE member_id IN (" . join("," $chan[2]) . ")";
```

if `$chan[2]` holds the list of the ids to be deleted. Also make sure that you only pass numeric values into the query to avoid sql injection problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
$member_ids = implode(", ", $chan);
"$query = "DELETE from members WHERE member_id IN ($member_ids)";
```

Answer (score 0):

The equality operator will delete only values that match the given value exactly. If you have multiple ids in an array, you need to use another condition. You can use the MYSQL function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), for example, if that is your database:

```
$ids = array(1, 2, 3);
$query = "DELETE FROM members WHERE FIND_IN_SET(member_id, '" . implode(',', $ids) . "')";
```

One more thing: be very very careful if you have received the ids from the user. [It might contain bogus data](http://xkcd.com/327/). Sanitization is done with [`mysql_escape_string()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php):

```
$ids = array_map('mysql_escape_string', $ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

implode answers given above are the correct way. Purely for the sake of making what happens there very clear; this is the code you'd use if implode didn't exist ( I take it $chan is a 2-D array so $chan[2] has 5 members,  use $chan if otherwise)

```
// start roll-your-own $member_id_cond = implode(", ",$chan[2]);
$member_id_cond = "";
foreach( $chan[2] as $key => $data) {
     $member_id_cond .= $data . ", ";
     if($key == 4)  {  //this is just to remove the last comma
           $member_id_cond = sub_str($member_id_cond, 0, -2);
     }
 }
 //end implode 
 $query = "DELETE FROM members WHERE member_id IN ($member_id_cond)";
```